# Очевидные запятые

Tags: пунктуация

**..однако, надежда на то, что это будет оценено, всё ещё теплится.**

/ сомневаюсь в запятых, ткните пальцем при очевидности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае запятая после "однако" не нужна. В значении противительного союза в начале предложения запятая не ставится. В сложном предложении запятая ставится до "однако", а не после. В вашем случае запятая стоит после "однако", поэтому она лишняя.

> Примечание. После союза однако может стоять обособленный оборот, и тогда запятая, оказавшаяся после однако, отделяет именно этот оборот: ***Однако, распахнув пахнущую казенной краской классную дверь, он убедился, что здесь всё обстояло по-старому (Фад.) — после союза деепричастный оборот.***

Иногда слово однако в начале предложения может выполнять функцию междометия и отделяться запятой именно на этом основании: ***Однако, какой ветер! (Ч.)***

> Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно начало предложения. Скорее всего, запятая после *однако* -- лишняя.

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127 :

> Слово *однако* является вводным, если
> стоит внутри или в конце предложения:
> *Ганин, однако, никогда не был слишком щедр на похвалу* (Тендр.). В значении
> противительного союза *однако* может
> соединять однородные члены предложения
> или части сложного предложения: *Отец
> обещал приехать из города рано, однако
> задержался; Туман заметно густел,
> однако крыши домов были еще видны; Так
> же легко, беззаботно и возвратился он
> в гостиницу. Однако что-то уже
> изменилось* (Бун.).

Comment: до этого идёт отдельная самостоятельная мысль, умозаключение...
оставлю запятую, спасибо

Comment: freelanSER: "... оставлю запятую".=== И всё-таки обратите внимание на это: "В значении противительного союза однако может соединять части... сложного предложения". Если у Вас именно этот случай, то запятая после "однако" не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

К примеру, верно поставлены запятые в предложении: "У многих, однако, надежда на то, что это будет оценено, всё ещё теплится".

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным в середине предложения, "однако" - вводное слово.

Comment: Vera: "К примеру, верно поставлены запятые в предложении: "У многих, однако, надежда на то, что это будет оценено, всё ещё теплится".
СПП с придаточным изъяснительным в середине предложения, "однако" - вводное слово."===  Vera,  а при чём тут упоминание об СПП? В Вашем примере "однако" стоит не между частями СПП (не соединяет эти части), а расположено В СЕРЕДИНЕ ПРОСТОГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ: "У многих, однако, надежда всё ещё теплится". В середине ПРОСТОГО предложения -- да, вводное.